# Proving a series convergent knowing that the sequence of arithmetic mean is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose partial sums $A_{n} $ of sereis $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k}$ satisfies $|A_{n}|\le Mn^{r} $ for some $r\lt 1$ and $\forall n=1,2,...$ 
Then prove that $\sum a_{n}/n $ is convergent.

The title can be easily justified by 
$|A_{n}|\le Mn^{r} \lt Mn$ 
 since $r\lt 1$ so that $|A_{n}/n|\lt M $.

I thought in following way

$|A_{n}|/n^{2} \lt M/n^{2-r}\quad \forall n..\quad(1)$

Let $u_{n}=|A_{n}|/n^{2}$ .Then 
$\sum u_{n} $ is convergent by comparison test and convergence of $p $  sereis applied in $(1)$

Again $s_{k}=\sum_{n=1}^{k} a_{n}/n $

$\quad\quad=\sum_{n=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n}/n^{2} $

I can't procced after this. I need to show $s_{k}$ is convergent.Please help.

Please dont close this question .I have seen the same question but I am curious to know if anything can be done in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Using summation by parts, you get for $p \le N\in \mathbb N$

$$\sum_{n=p}^N \frac {a_n}{n} = \frac{A_N}{N}- \sum_{n=p}^{N-1} A_n \left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Hence

$$\begin{aligned}\left\vert\sum_{n=p}^N \frac {a_n}{n} \right\vert &\le \left\vert \frac{A_N}{N}\right\vert + \sum_{n=p}^{N-1} \frac{\vert A_n \vert}{n^2}\\
&\le \left\vert \frac{A_N}{N}\right\vert + M\sum_{n=p}^{N-1} \frac{n^r}{n^2}\\
&\le M N^{r-1}+ M\sum_{n=p}^{N-1} n^{r-2}\end{aligned}$$

As $r<1$, $\lim\limits_{N \to \infty} N^{r-1} =0$ and the series $\sum n^{r-2}$ converges. Based on that, we can prove that $\sum a_n/n$ is Cauchy and therefore converges.

Comment: Thanks sir / madam ..but I think a term. $ -A_{p}/p^{r} $ is missing in first line..However taking modulus on both sides manages the situation ..Am I right ?

Comment: Yes you’re right. As you noted, the conclusion still holds.

Comment: sorry..it is $ -A_{p}/p $